# How can I create a foreign keys of text type in MariaDB or MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, mariadb

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE first_table(
my_id TEXT(6) NOT NULL,
content VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(my_id(6))
) Engine=InnoDB charset utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE second_table(
another_id TEXT(6) NOT NULL,
my_id TEXT(6) NOT NULL,
another_content VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(another_id(6))
) Engine=InnoDB charset utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

But in the second table  I can't create a foreign key that references the first table, first I've tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE second_table
ADD FOREIGN KEY (my_id)
REFERENCES first_table(my_id)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

And got this error:

```
ERROR 1170 (42000): BLOB/TEXT column 'my_id' used in key specification without a key length
MariaDB [base_ventas]>
```

So, I tried to specify the key length like this:

```
ALTER TABLE second_table
ADD FOREIGN KEY (my_id(6))
REFERENCES first_table(my_id)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

And I got this error:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `base_ventas`.`#sql-1a08_23c` 
(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

This doesn't happen with numeric ids but I need to have string type ids, it can be done, or I am missing something?

Comment: What is the point of `TEXT(6)` here? Using these for id values, foreign keys, is a really bad plan.

Comment: @tadman I'm in the college and my db professor made the structure, and now I'm trying to implement it, my choice could be a numeric id mediumint or int maybe

Comment: This schema is just plain *wrong* on so many levels. Using `TEXT` for identifiers is an automatic fail in any sane code review. If these are numerical, use `INT`, if not, `VARCHAR(6)`.

Comment: Did they say SQL TEXT specifically or did they mean text in an everyday sense applicable to VARCHAR? If they said text, how is using an id instead ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry to inform that it's not possible.

According to [MySql Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> Index prefixes on foreign key columns are not supported. One
>   consequence of this is that BLOB and TEXT columns cannot be included
>   in a foreign key because indexes on those columns must always include
>   a prefix length.

And [MariaDB Documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/foreign-keys/):

> The columns in the child table must be an index, or the leftmost part
>   of an index. Index prefixes are not supported (thus, TEXT and BLOB
>   columns cannot be used as foreign keys)

If you really need alphanumeric keys, consider using something like char or varchar instead. The easiest, most generic, and most common approach is to use numeric keys, such as INT.

Comment: I have a doubt: my professor in the college says always use non-numeric ids like "pro-001" for products or "usr-001" for users, but, from what I know using int is faster and easier because of auto increment, I think my professor is trying to make the data more legible but considering the performance penalty, should I follow her rule in production in non-distributed systems?

Comment: "pro-001" is fine.  But it should be declared either `CHAR(7)` if truly fixed length, or `VARCHAR(22)` (or some 'sane' max length).  `TEXT` will not work.  `INDEX(foo(6))` will not work.

Comment: @RickJames, it is totally fine?, or somewhat bad in production? I've read that alphanumeric GUI is used in a technique with systems that use distributed databases, but I want to know if I should avoid this on databases that are not distributed, for example in small companies, or it doesn't matter at all?

Comment: GUIDs are inefficient in huge tables.  `AUTO_INCREMENT` is a common thing to use for creating unique ids for a table.  Research that.

Comment: "if you can go with int, go with int" I'd say. You don't really need an ID value to have a prefix of your table name because you already know from which table this value is coming from. Also by specifying `pro-001` and CHAR(7) you're not only limiting your possible ids to 1000 values, but you're also storing 4 bytes of useless data per record, which is not specific to the record itself.
I go with the auto increments because not only it's easier to use and more performing, you can get 2 billions of different ids by using only 4 bytes. And it also makes sense in every possible way.